# Connect an in-line fan to the thermostat

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac

I’m trying to connect an inline booster fan to my ecobee3. The fan I have is an AC INFINITY CLOUDLINE T6. I would like to have it turn on whenever the fan of the HVAC is turned on.

The in-line fan has 3 wires (hot, neutral, and ground). I cut off the three prong plug off of the fan wire and soldered a 20 awg wire to run it to the thermostat. I can solder another bit of 20 awg  to extend it to the furnace, if need be.

From what I have read, I believe I need to connect the fan to a relay and connect some wires from the thermostat to the relay as well. Apparently, I am able to use a RIB2401B relay.

I’m having trouble understanding how exactly the relay should be wired to the thermostat and the three wires off of the fan. I’m a complete novice with this stuff so I’d really appreciate if someone could explain it to me like I’m 5.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Some photos might help

Comment: The fan is going to run off power switched through the relay. However I'm not super comfortable giving a full answer because there's a fair bit to learn here to do this properly.

Comment: That’s understandable. So far, I understand that the relay control side will be hooked up to the thermostat to turn off/on the switch. I’m going to connect the power for the in line fan along with a 120 v to the relay (n/o) contacts.

Comment: I am just not sure which wires on the thermostat should be connected to the relay control side that would signal the the turning off and on of the furnace fan.

Comment: Also, is 20 awg cable safe to use to extend the three prong plug wire of the fan to the thermostat?

Comment: Unless the mfg declared it was OK to but off the plug, you may have just voided any UL listing.  Also, I didn't know Ecobees could control booster fans directly.

Comment: You need to power your fan from the HVAC unit (not from the thermostat), and you need to use the same awg wire as the fan was supplied with.